# How to make folders for individual files within a directory via bash script?

Tags: bash, file, directory

So I've got a movie collection that's dumped into a single folder (I know, bad practice in retrospect.) I want to organize things a bit so I can use Radarr to grab all the appropriate metadata, but I need all the individual files in their own folders. I created the script below to try and automate the process a bit, but I get the following error.

**Script**

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in /the/path/to/files/* ;
 do
    [[ -d $f ]] && continue
    mkdir "${f%.*}"
    mv "$f" "${f%.*}"
done
```

**EDIT**

So I've now run the script through Shellcheck.net per the suggestion of Benjamin W.  It doesn't throw any errors according to the site, though I still get the same errors when I try running the command.

**EDIT 2***

No errors now, but the script does nothing when executed.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ will tell you that you can't have blanks around `=` in an assignment.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question like that, it's a totally different question now. It only affects one answer (mine), but consider that things like my first sentence in the answer don't make any sense any longer. You could make a new question, or follow up in comments on my answer (as you did).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignments are evaluated only once, and not whenever the variable being assigned to is used, which I think is what your script assumes.

You could use a loop like this:

```sh
for f in /path/to/all/the/movie/files/*; do
    mkdir "${f%.*}"
    mv "$f" "${f%.*}"
done
```

This uses [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) instead of `cut` to get rid of the file extension.

Comment: So when I try running that instead of my script, it fails because it attempts to move the folder into itself. ```mv: cannot move '/path/` to a subdirectory of itself, '/path/````

Comment: @TaylorCohron You're running just these 4 lines, nothing else, right? You don't have to do your other assignments for this solution to work.

Comment: Just the 4 lines indeed, the only change I made was updating the path to the correct folder. Given the wildcard at the end of the path (I'm assuming the * works that way in bash anyway) that it would know it's trying to do it for each file, not the parent folder itself? Is there anything else I need to do to specify for each file **in** the folder?

Comment: @TaylorCohron `for f in /some/path/*` should indeed not try to do anything to the `/some/path` directory itself. It sounds like your directory contain not only files, but also directories? That would cause an error like you're seeing. If that's the case, you can add a check to make sure you're only handling files, like `[[ -d $f ]] && continue` to skip directories.

Comment: Where would I add that argument? I assume in the definition of the loop, but I got errors doing that, so I added it into the function itself as the first line and the script would run, but it wouldn't make any actual modifications to the folder. This is the script as I have currently is in the post now

Comment: @TaylorCohron As the first statement in the loop.

Comment: @TaylorCohron Do any of your files not have a file extension? That would also cause an error because you'd try to create a directory with the same name as an existing file. It does work as intended so when testing locally for files with extensions.

Comment: Sorry for the edit, duly noted for any future questions I ask. All the files have either a .mkv, .avi, or .mp4 extension, they're all video files. I just tried it with the statement as the first in the loop, as shown above, still nothing happens on execution of the script. No hidden files or anything. Totally lost as to why it'd do this given the logic seems right.

Comment: @TaylorCohron Try `set -x` before you run the code to see what instructions are actually executed. Do you use a strange path? What's the *exact* for loop declaration you're using?

Comment: I figured it out, I simply had forgotten that the directory name was changed, and I was trying to run the script on a directory with no files in it